# Sonata admin send model_manager to custom field ModelAutocompleteType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

Hello i am using symfony 5.4 with sonata admin. I created custom AppModelAutocopleteType

```
class AppModelAutocompleteType extends AbstractType
```

{

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'callback' => static function (AdminInterface $admin, array $property, $value) {
            AutocompleteForIntegerAndString::execute($admin, $property, $value);
        },
        'to_string_callback' => function($entity, $property) {
            return $entity->getLabel();
        },
        'minimum_input_length' => 1,
        'delay' => 333,
    ]);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return ModelAutocompleteType::class;
}
```

}

and in sonata admin class (Lead entity) in filter section i add this (networkProvider is relation to Lead entity)

```
->add('networkProvider', ModelFilter::class, [
            'field_type' => AppModelAutocompleteType::class,
            'field_options' => [
                'property' => ['code', 'name'],
                'class' => Lead::class,
                'model_manager' => $this->getModelManager(),
            ],
        ])
```

thing is when i enable in frontend my filter it shows up correctly and when i type something i get error. In profiler (ajax request) i can see this problem

```
Could not find admin for code "".
```

Based on what i tried it looks like maybe something wrong with model_manager, i don't know if i sent it properly.

Any help how can i create custom ModelAutocompleteType which will work with sonata admin is really appreciate.